# nested json c# object deserialization

Tags: c#, json.net

i have the following json string (jsonString)

```
[
{
"name":"Fruits",
"references":[
    {"stream":{"type":"reference","size":"original",id":"1"}},
    ],
"arts":[
    {"stream":{"type":"art","size":"original","id":"4"}},
    {"stream":{"type":"art","size":"medium","id":"9"}},
    ]
}
]
```

and the following C# objects

```
    class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Stream> References { get; set; }
        public List<Stream> Arts { get; set; }

        public Item()
        {
        }
    }

    class Stream
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Size { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public Stream()
        {
        }
    }
```

and the following code

```
        Item item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(jsonString);
```

when I run the code, it creteas the correct number of references and arts, but each stream has null value (type = null, size = null).

is it posible to do this json.net deserializeobject method or should I manually deserialize ?

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: Okay, ignore the previous answer. The problem is that your arrays (references and arts) contain objects which *in turn* contain the relevant data. Basically you've got one layer of wrapping too many. For example, this JSON works fine:

```
[
{
"name":"Fruits",
"references":[
    {"Type":"reference","Size":"original","Id":"1"},
    ],
"arts":[
    {"Type":"art","Size":"original","id":"4"},
    {"type":"art","size":"medium","id":"9"},
    ]
}
]
```

If you can't change the JSON, you may need to introduce a new wrapper type into your object model:

```
public class StreamWrapper
{
    public Stream Stream { get; set; }
}
```

Then make your `Item` class have `List<StreamWrapper>` variables instead of `List<Stream>`. Does that help?

Comment: Jon Skeet, thanks for the reply.

I get the same result as you.

The issue is that for me ... the Stream object properties are either null or 0.

that is 

    item.References[0].Type == null

and so on ... 

does that not happen to you ?

Comment: @Iboregard: Ah, sorry - I'd thought your `List<T>` values were null. Investigating...